# How can I check whether a transaction spends the output of an RBF transaction?

Tags: json-rpc, replace-by-fee

A transaction can be RBF if itself is a RBF, or it spends outputs from a RBF transaction.

Is there a way to use bitcoin RPC node to check if a transaction is spending outputs from a RBF transaction?

Answer (score 3):

The `getrawmempool` RPC command, in verbose mode, produces an output that contains all known mempool transactions for your nodes. This output contains a `bip125-replaceable` boolean field which you can use to determine if a tx is explicitly or implicitly replaceable by fee.

Comment: `getrawmempool` returns the tx ids only, not contains any tx info, I'm afraid. Reference: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list

Comment: BTW, looks like `gettransaction` provides `bip125-replaceable` info, however it is no longer supported from `0.10.0`. Unfortunately mine is newer, so it is useless too. https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-cli/gettransaction

Comment: @GiangNguyen If verbose is false, it returns only txids. If verbose is true, it returns a detailed JSON object for each transaction.

Comment: awesome! I didn't notice that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Based on Raghav Sood's answer, I found the more specific answer to the OP would be using `getmempoolentry`, in order to get an individual transaction info. Otherwise you'll be flooded with tons of transactions. Documented [here](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-cli/getmempoolentry)

You can also use `gettransaction`, it returns `bip125-replaceable` flag as well, however just for Bitcore prior to 0.10.0 according to [this](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-cli/gettransaction)

Comment: Ah, good point, I didn't actually realize an option for a single tx was added in 0.13!